# How to define an xpath from a different level of divs

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver

In the below `HTML` I would like to define the `xpath` as one but the object identifier are in different div level.

Screenshot of the div highlighted in blue and yellow.

[image]

Actual HTML below:

```
<div class="option mli-body-1 selected ng-star-inserted" tabindex="0" ng-reflect-klass="option mli-body-1" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">
    <mat-checkbox class="mat-checkbox mat-accent mat-checkbox-checked" ng-reflect-checked="true" id="mat-checkbox-97">
        <label class="mat-checkbox-layout" for="mat-checkbox-97-input">
            <div class="mat-checkbox-inner-container">
                <input class="mat-checkbox-input cdk-visually-hidden" type="checkbox" id="mat-checkbox-97-input" tabindex="0" aria-label="" aria-checked="true">
                <div class="mat-checkbox-ripple mat-ripple" matripple="" ng-reflect-centered="true" ng-reflect-radius="25" ng-reflect-animation="[object Object]" ng-reflect-disabled="false" ng-reflect-trigger="[object HTMLLabelElement]"></div>
                <div class="mat-checkbox-frame"></div>
                <div class="mat-checkbox-background">
                    <svg xml:space="preserve" class="mat-checkbox-checkmark" focusable="false" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                        <path class="mat-checkbox-checkmark-path" d="M4.1,12.7 9,17.6 20.3,6.3" fill="none" stroke="white"></path>
                    </svg>
                    <div class="mat-checkbox-mixedmark"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <span class="mat-checkbox-label">
                <span style="display:none">&nbsp;</span>
                <mli-selected-text ng-reflect-text="Inforce (3)" ng-reflect-highlighted="">
                    <span>Inforce (3)</span>
                </mli-selected-text>
            </span>
        </label>
    </mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

The "aria-checked" has to be `TRUE` and the text inside the span must be 'Inforce'
I am using this code, but the problem is that, even text is not inforce, it will always found the object

```
//input[@aria-checked='true']/following::span[contains(text(),'Inforce')]
```

Comment: can you provide your actual html code rather than image

Comment: could you please provide actual html code in place of image ?

Comment: Hi Pritam, I have updated the post to include the actual HTML, thanks

Comment: Great! It works,Thank you very much for this. I have trying trial and error for one day and you solve in just less than a minute. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you now up vote my answer as it is working for you ?

Comment: Done, But is not recorded as I have low reputation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use following XPath :**

```
//input[@aria-checked='true']//parent::node()//following-sibling ::span//span[contains(text(),'Inforce')]
```

Comment: They work the same with my defined xpath, Because I have 4 levels of Div, I am checking the aria-checked because it indicated that the checkbox is checked/selected, However, when I am trying to change the span text to "Expired" which aria-checked is false, it is still found which should be not